# ObservableCollection Binding Exception - ListView ItemSource Xamarin

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I want to bind a listview to my viewmodel but I get `ArgumentNullException`.
I use xamarin.forms and the exception appears in android and ios projects  but **not in uwp**.

Itemsource returns an exception when I use binding with the viewmodel. When i don't use binding in my xaml the exception disappears.

```
System.ArgumentNullException has been thrown
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: element
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<T> pages = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        public ObservableCollection<T> Pages 
        {
            get { return pages; }
            set
            {
                pages = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Pages");
            }
        }
```

**VM Constructor**

```
public ViewModel()
{
    _service = new Service();
    someitems = _service.getitems();
    Pages = new ObservableCollection<T>(someitems);;
}
```

**Service**

`return new ObservableCollection<T>(items);`

**View**

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}"
```

The problem seems to be the setter `pages = value;`

What is wrong?

Comment: What is in your `OnPropertyChanged()` method?

Comment: @slugster `var handler = PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null)
handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my **service** to an `async` data source and finally I used:

**Constructor**

```
public ViewModel()
{
   InitPages();
}
```

**Async Init()**

```
private async void Init()
{
   Pages = await ServiceFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code posted it seems you are trying to initialize the Pages collection with null value.

```
public ViewModel()
{
    Pages = new ObservableCollection<T>(someitems);;
}
```

In your ViewModel constructor `someitems` seems to be null. I assume this since you are using `Generics` and at that moment you probably don't know the type is gonna be used.

If you want/need to initialize it with a value you can do it passing a parameter in the ViewModel constructor:

```
public ViewModel(IList<T> someitems)
{
    Pages = new ObservableCollection<T>(someitems);
}
```

**Note**: You don't need to create a backing field when working `ObservableCollection`, with an Auto-Property would be enough, but be advised that using this you must keep the same instance and when replacing objects you will do it clearing `Clear()` and adding `Add()` the new items.

```
public ObservableCollection<T> Pages { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like `someitems` is null but it's not as I see from debugging. The problem appears only in ios and android, in uwp the listview works properly. I used the note but I have the same problem.

Comment: If you remove the `someitems` from the Collection initialization what happens? It crash?

Comment: It seems it's null, hence the exception. Could you update the original post with the complete ViewModel?

Comment: What I see is that the program is not awaiting for the result of your service (you shouldn't do heavy operations in the constructor of a class) and it's continuing, leaving the `someitems` as null. A possible solution for this is initialize the collection as empty then using a `Command` send to get the data and update the property, this will notify the UI to refresh accordingly.

Comment: Your statement *"You don't need to create a backing field when working ObservableCollection, with an Auto-Property is enough"* is not strictly accurate. You *can* use just an auto property, but then there is no notification to the binding subsystem if the collection gets swapped out for a new one (or when the property initially gets populated).

Comment: @slugster totally agree with you and perhaps I didn't use the right words to express it. I lacked to explain the implications of using an auto-property with the ObservableCollection.